# Django1.8 or less queryset: filter multiple datetimes by hour

Tags: python, django, datetime, filter, django-queryset

I have a model with a datetime field that I want to filter by hour, the problem is that there's multiple datetimes, making the datetime.now() soluction not realible for this case. Also, if we try gt/lt/gte/lte/in to the hour it doesn't work.

The scenario is that if the hour is less then 12 then returns "morning", if it is between 12 and 18 returns "afternoon" and if it is greater then 18 returns "night".

Model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    datetime_field = models.DateTimeField()
    name = models.CharField()
```

Data example:

```
1. 2012/10/2 22:00
2. 2015/2/15 15:00
3. 2017/3/2 9:00
```

Expected queryset:

```
Night = queryset.filter(datetime_field__hour__gte=18)
Afternoon = queryset.filter(datetime_field__hour__lt=18, datetime_field__hour__gte=12)
Morning = queryset.filter(datetime_field__hour__lt=12)
```

Result:

```
1. Night
2. Afternoon
3. Morning
```

Comment: Django 1.9+ does support chaining hour lookups e.g. `__hour__gte`.

Comment: Please add your model and a useful result.

Comment: Thanks @Alasdair for the answer, in this case the Django is 1.8 and I forgot to mention in the question.